# Which linear model summary row corresponds to which term in formula?

Tags: r, formula

Summary of a linear model uses certain strings to denote coefficients in its output, for example:

```
summary(lm(
 target ~ some.bool + some.factor + some.factor*some.value +
          some.factor:some.other,
 data.frame(target=rnorm(100), some.bool=sample(c(T, F), 100, T),
  some.factor=sample(c('Y', 'N', 'M'), 100, T), some.value=rnorm(100),
  some.other=rnorm(100))))
```

results in a table with names:
`some.boolTRUE`,
`some.factorN`,
`some.factorY`,
`some.value`,
`some.factorN:some.value`,
`some.factorY:some.value`,
`some.factorM:some.other`,
`some.factorN:some.other`,
`some.factorY:some.other`.

How do I programmatically find out which rows of the table correspond to which terms of the input formula? I'd like to get some mapping, like:

```
`some.boolTRUE`            → some.bool
`some.factorN`:            → some.factor, some.factor*some.value
`some.factorY`:            → some.factor, some.factor*some.value
`some.value`:              → some.factor*some.value
`some.factorN:some.value`: → some.factor*some.value
`some.factorN:some.other`: → some.factor:some.other
```

My goal is to prepare a specific form of presentation for results where the data from linear regression are presented grouped by the input terms.

Comment: Perhaps you need to consult a statistical text. FWIW, `x*y` is short hand for `x + y + x:y`.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik: I know that. I just want to match rows with terms as entered by the user, regardless of what user entered, programmatically.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on what exactly the input and expected output are and why you need this?

Comment: @Roland: thank you for suggestion, I added an example and my goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I noticed the code that generates these names are deep inside the `model.matrix` function called as an external C function. I can recover the names built out of a term (with `term` being an expression/symbol object taken out of the formula itself) using a hack like:

```
names.for.term <- function(term, data, order.as.in=term) {
  # construct a simple formula that has only the requested term
  f <- formula(substitute(~ x, list(x=term)))

  # make a terms object for manipulation
  term.terms <- terms(f, data=data)

  # what order do we want to consider variables in?
  requested.order <- na.omit(match(
    row.names(attr(terms(order.as.in), 'factors')),
    row.names(attr(term.terms, 'factors'))))

  # force the order of variables (setting row.names is enough;
  # values in this array are not important for the process of building
  # strings if you have only a single summand. if not, good luck)
  row.names(attr(term.terms, 'factors')) <-
    row.names(attr(term.terms, 'factors'))[requested.order]

  # we need model frame object to have columns in the same order as
  # rows above; types of variables (e.g. factors) are inferred from here
  m <- model.frame(f, data)[requested.order]

  # call deep into C code
  dimnames(.External2(stats:::C_modelmatrix, term.terms, m))[[2]][-1]
}
```

Ugly, but works. As strings depend on the order of variables this function call encounters in the term, you might want to pass the full formula as `order.as.in`. Now the only thing left is to reverse the mapping, which is trivial at this point.